# XR Hands don't appear when I put down controllers

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I'm trying to get hand tracking working in Unity using the XR Interaction Toolkit (XRI) and XR Hands.

I'm testing this in the Unity Editor on an Oculus/Meta Quest 2 headset via Oculus Link or Air Link.

I put my controllers down, but the hand prefabs aren't appearing as if the cameras never see my hands.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Oculus/Meta Quest app is set as the default OpenXR runtime. You can do this by opening the Oculus app going to Settings and changing "OpenXR Runtime" as seen in the screen shot.

[image: Oculus app settings page]